# Proof of special case of Fermat's Last Theorem

Tags: number-theory, proof-writing

Please help evaluate mathematical clarity of a proof of this simple proposition:
*If $n \geq 3$
is an odd integer and
$x, y, z > 0$
are integers such that
$x^{n} + y^{n} = z^{n},$
then
$z$
cannot be a prime-power.*

**Proof.**
To prove the assertion note for a start that if there exists a counterexample to it
then we have
$$z < x+y < 2z,$$
where the inequality on the left follows from the relations
$(x+y)^{n} > x^{n} + y^{n} = z^{n}$
and the inequality on the right follows from the relations
$x, y < z$
which follow from the implications
$x \geq z \Rightarrow y \leq 0$
and
$y \geq z \Rightarrow x \leq 0.$
Moreover,
from the equation
$x^{n} + y^{n} = z^{n}$
and that
$n$
is an odd integer,
it follows that
$$(x+y) \mid z^{n}.$$
Since
$z$
is a prime-power,
there exist a prime
$u$
and a positive integer
$m$
such that
$$z^{n} = (u^{m})^{n}.$$
By the inequality
$z < x+y$
there is a positive integer
$m'$
such that
$$x+y = u^{m'},\ \ m+1 \leq m' \leq mn,$$
whence
$$x+y = u^{m'} \geq 2u^{m} = 2z$$
(with equality if
$m = 1$
and
$u = m' = 2$),
contradicting the inequality
$x+y < 2z.$
Thus $z$
cannot be any prime-power.

Comment: +1 I read it after the 3rd edit and it looks very clear  and right for me.

Comment: The title is really bad. It does not say anything about the mathematicl content of the  post.

Comment: @miracle173: Thanks you very much for your attention. What alternative would you suggest? Or if you are willing, simply edit the title and I will be okay with that :)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Your statement is false. If $n=1$, then $$1^1+1^1=2^1$$ shows that $x+y$ can be a prime, and $z$ can be a prime power.

The problem in your proof is that you say $z<x+y$ which is not true in this case since $(x+y)^n$ is not greater than $x^n + y^n$.

*AFTER EDIT*:

I find your proof very hard to read. My complaints are:

- In the beginning, you don not specify explicitly that you are proving by contradiction. You only say that if a counterexample exists, then something something. A more readable way would be to say

> Let us prove the statement by contradiction. Let $x,y,z$ be such numbers that $x+y$ is prime or $y$ is a prime power

Now, my **MAIN** objection: in the middle of your proof, you say "if $z$ is a prime power". Sure, I agree, but even in a counterexample you assume exists for the purpose of your proof by contradiction, the number $z$ *may not be a prime power*. Even simply having $x+y$ be a prime is enough to constitute a counterexample.

*After your second edit*:

My initial complaint still stands. In the beginning, it is unclear that you are using contradiction.Apart from that, you write that from $x^n + y^n = z^n$ and $n$ being odd, it follows that $(x+y)|z^n$ which could use some clarification (just to make it clear).

The next unclear point is the inequality $m+1\leq m' \leq mn$. Where did this come from? Sure, from $u^m=z<x+y=u^{m'}$, I can see that $m'\geq m+1$, but why is $m'\leq mn$? You need to clarify this in your proof.

Comment: suggesting an issue with the assertion $(x+y)^{n} > x^{n} + y^{n}$

Comment: @Henry Thank you, was just about to write that down.

Comment: Thank you so much for your interest. I misspecified the range of $n$. And your answer does not mention the math. clarity. :)

Comment: @Comeseeconquer I see no reason to judge the mathematical clarity of a statement that is false. I will reevaluate it now that you changed the statement.

Comment: @5xum: Alright, thanks for your attention.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer See my edit, I still think your proof is faulty.

Comment: Yeah, I see. Let me think. :) Indeed, to begin with "if there is a counterexample ..." is logically equivalent to "we argue by contradiction ...". I just want to prevent the cliche! :)

Comment: I do not understand " the number z may not be a prime power."?

Comment: @Comeseeconquer The negation of your statement is: "there exists some $x,y,z$ such that $x^n+y^n=z^n$ and ($x+y$ is prime or $z$ is a prime power)". Therefore, a triplet $x,y,z$ where $x+y$ is prime and $z$ is *not* a prime power is one possibility you must analyze if you are doing a proof by contradiction.

Comment: @5xum: Ah ha, got the point. Guess what? Originally my conclusion is simply that $z$ cannot be a prime power. So that part $x+y$ so and so is artificially added and not about logic. Sorry for causing your confusion! Please see my edit.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer I edited my answer again.

Comment: @5xum: Thanks you so much for your efforts and time. Very valuable! Incidentally, the inequality $m' \leq mn$ holds because if not then $x+y > z^{n}$ so that $x^{n} + y^{n} > x+y > z^{n}$, contradiction.

Comment: @Comeseeconquer OK, but then writing this down is necesary, otherwise it looks like the inequality is pulled out of thin air.